# flutter new build system error after upgrade to XCode version 12

Tags: flutter, hyperlink, command, new-operator

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Legacy build system detected, removing /Users/simonwong/aipos/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
Xcode build done.                                           10.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
↳
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: can you share the screen shot after running the command "flutter doctor -v" on terminal.

Comment: Running "flutter pub get" in aipass...                              3.8s
Wrote 71 files.

All done!
[✓] Flutter: is fully installed. (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2 20D64 darwin-x64, locale en-MY)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices: is fully installed. (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS: is fully installed. (Xcode 12.4)
[✓] Android Studio: is fully installed. (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device: is fully installed. (1 available)